# array_unique on inside arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

so I've got that array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [date_add] => 2016 - 12 - 01[0] => 2016 - 12 - 01
    ) [1] => Array(
        [date_add] => 2016 - 11 - 01[0] => 2016 - 12 - 01
    ) [2] => Array(
        [date_add] => 2016 - 12 - 02[0] => 2016 - 12 - 02
    ) [3] => Array(
        [date_add] => 2016 - 12 - 01[0] => 2016 - 12 - 01
    ) [4] => Array(
        [date_add] => 2016 - 12 - 01[0] => 2016 - 12 - 01
    )
)
```

I want to use **array_unique()** to don't let repeat the dates, my problem is that it only works on normal elements of an array, my question is how to do it on a inside arrays?

Comment: Is it a mysql-query result? If yes - filter values there

Answer (score 0):

> You can use PHP's [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to make
>   this work.

You can try this:

```
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arr)));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @m1u - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!